# Validação email e senha usando Keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Estou usando o código que me diga se ambos emails são idênticos, se ambas senhas são idênticas e se elas tem no mínimo 8 e no máximo 10 caracteres. E somente se os emails foram iguais, senhas iguais e no tamanho correto que o botão de cadastrar do formulário aparece.

Porém como consegui usar apenas o `keyup` no `email2` e `senha2`, se o usuário voltar e digitar algo na senha ou email, não muda para erro o `input`.

O que queria era saber como por o mesmo evento com as mesma regras do `keyup` do `email2` e `senha2` também no `email` e `senha`, para que fosse validado em ambos os campos de confirmação.

E note que nem consegui ainda restringir e validar o email, só se são ou não idênticos.

```js
$('#email2').on('keyup', function () {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var email2 = $("#email2").val();

    if (email != email2) {
        $("#message").html("Os email não são identicos").css('color', 'red');
        $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
    } else {
        $("#message").html("Os email são identicos").css('color', 'green');
        $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
    }
    $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
    $('#senha2').on('keyup', function (){
        var password = $("#senha").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#senha2").val();
        if (password.length < 8 || password.length  > 16) { 
            $("#divCheckPassword2").html("As senhas precisam ter no minimo 8 caracteres e no máximo 16").css('color', 'red');
            $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
        } else {
            $("#divCheckPassword2").html("").css('color', 'green');
            $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
        }

        if (password != confirmPassword) {
             $("#divCheckPassword").html("As senhas não são").css('color', 'red');
             $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
        } else {
            $("#divCheckPassword").html("Senhas identicas").css('color', 'green');
            $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
        }

        if (password != confirmPassword ||  password.length < 8 || 
            password.length  > 16 || email != email2){
            $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
        } else {
            $('#validator').prop('disabled' , false);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que você pode separar os eventos para cada tipo de validação: de email e de senha:

```
$('#email, #email2').on('keyup', validarEmail); // chama a função ref. ao email
$('#senha, #senha2').on('keyup', validarSenha); // chama a função ref. à senha
```

E usar uma função para controlar o botão de cadastrar:

```
function valida(){

   $('#validator')
   .prop('disabled', val_email && val_senha && val_senha2 ? false : true);

}
```

Esse função será chamada nos eventos `keyup` e só irá habilitar o botão se as 3 variáveis (`val_email`, `val_senha` e `val_senha2`) forem `true`.

Outro detalhe é o botão já vir com o atributo disabled no HTML:

```
<button id="validator" disabled>Cadastrar</button>
                          ↑
```

**Veja exemplo:**

```js
$(function(){

   // declaro variáveis de controle
   var val_email, val_senha, val_senha2;
   
   function valida(){
      
      $('#validator')
      .prop('disabled', val_email && val_senha && val_senha2 ? false : true);
      
   }

   function validarEmail(){
  
      var email = $("#email").val().trim();
      var email2 = $("#email2").val().trim();

      // só irá verificar se os campos tiverem algo  
      if(email && email2){
         if(email != email2){

            $("#message")
            .html("Os emails não são idênticos")
            .css('color', 'red');
            val_email = false;

         }else{

            $("#message")
            .html("Os emails são idênticos")
            .css('color', 'green');
            val_email = true;

         }

         // chama a função de controle do botão
         valida();

      }

   }

   function validarSenha(){

      var senha = $("#senha").val();
      var senha2 = $("#senha2").val();

      // só irá verificar se os campos tiverem algo
      if(senha && senha2){
    
         if(senha.length < 8 || senha.length > 10){
   
            $("#divCheckPassword2")
            .html("As senhas precisam ter no mínimo 8 caracteres e no máximo 10")
            .css('color', 'red');
            val_senha = false;
   
         }else{
   
            $("#divCheckPassword2")
            .html("8 caracteres e no máximo 10")
            .css('color', 'green');
            val_senha = true;
   
         }
       
         if(senha != senha2){
   
            $("#divCheckPassword")
            .html("As senhas não são iguais")
            .css('color', 'red');
            val_senha2 = false;
   
         }else{
   
            $("#divCheckPassword").html("Senhas idênticas")
            .css('color', 'green');
            val_senha2 = true;
         }
         
         // chama a função de controle do botão
         valida();

      }
   }
  
   $('#email, #email2').on('keyup', validarEmail);
   $('#senha, #senha2').on('keyup', validarSenha);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
E-mail: <input type="email" id="email" autofocus>
<br>
Confirmar e-mail: <input type="email" id="email2">
<br>
<div id="message"></div>
<br><br>
Senha: <input type="password" id="senha">
<br>
Confirmar senha: <input type="password" id="senha2">
<br>
<div id="divCheckPassword"></div>
<div id="divCheckPassword2"></div>
<br>
<button id="validator" disabled>Cadastrar</button>
```

Comment: Gostei bastante da sua lógica, mas alterei o código lá em cima, se tivesse usando tbm para ver se o email é valido, e adicionando essa verificação para ativar o botão de cadastro, teria como?

Comment: Poderia fazer desta forma: https://jsfiddle.net/mohqz12k/

Comment: amigo, virei seu fã, perfeito!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer desta forma, o código foi explicado através dos comentários.

```js
//Iniciar script somente depois de carregar todo o html(dom)
$(function(){

  $('#validator').prop('disabled', true);

  //Separa a validação de e-mail
  function validarEmail(){
  
    var email = $("#email");
    var email2 = $("#email2");
  
    if (email.val() != email2.val()) {
      $("#message").html("Os email não são identicos").css('color', 'red');
      $('#validator').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#message").html("Os email são identicos").css('color', 'green');
      $('#validator').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }

  //Separa a validação de senha
  function validarSenha(){
  
    var senha = $("#senha");
    var senha2 = $("#senha2");
    
    var minLength = 8;
    var maxLength = 10;
    
    if (senha.val().length < minLength || senha.val().length > maxLength) {
      $("#divCheckPassword2").html("As senhas precisam ter no minimo " + minLength + " caracteres e no máximo " + maxLength).css('color', 'red');
      $('#validator').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
      $('#validator').prop('disabled', true);
      $("#divCheckPassword2").html("" + minLength + " caracteres e no máximo " + maxLength).css('color', 'green');
    }
    
    if (senha.val() != senha2.val()) {
      $("#divCheckPassword").html("As senhas não são iguais").css('color', 'red');
      $('#validator').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#divCheckPassword").html("Senhas identicas").css('color', 'green');
      $('#validator').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
  
  /**
  * Os eventos foram separados, já que o evento keyup da "senha2" 
  * só funcionária caso o evento de "email2" fosse acionado 
  * em conjunto, o que não aconteceria 
  *
  * Assim você chama a função em qualquer elemento adicionando
  * os eventos que desejar, e ao alterar o código de alguma regra
  * esta mudança será somenta na função reponsável pela aquela
  * validação.
  */
  
  $('#email').on('keyup', function() {
    validarEmail();
    validarSenha();
  });

  $('#senha').on('keyup', function() {
    validarEmail();
    validarSenha();
  });
  
  $('#email2').on('keyup', function() {
    validarEmail();
    validarSenha();
  });

  $('#senha2').on('keyup', function() {
    validarEmail();
    validarSenha();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="validator">
  <div id="validator">

  </div>
  <div id="divCheckPassword">

  </div>
  <div id="divCheckPassword2">

  </div>  
</div>

<div>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="email2">Confirmar e-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email2" name="email2">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="senha">Senha (minimo 8 e máximo 10):</label>
    <input type="password" id="senha" name="senha"
           minlength="8" required>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="senha2">Confirmar senha (minimo 8 e máximo 10):</label>
    <input type="password" id="senha2" name="senha2"
           minlength="8" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, mas agora ele não da a validação apra a senha, memso que tenha mais de 8 caracteres e sejam identicas, para tudo na parte de erro das senhas

Comment: certo deu perfeito, mais como validar agora essa parte com ele
`code`function validar(){
     if  (email != email2.val() ||  senha.val().length < 8 || senha.val().length > 16 || senha.val() != senha2.val()){
    $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
}else {
    $('#validator').prop('disabled' , false);
}
  }`code`

Comment: eu não mexi na parte da validação, somente nos eventos, copia a sua validação, mas de qualquer forma, vou alterar :)

Comment: só poso agradecer a sua ajuda amigo

Comment: Editei e agora esta funcionando a validação

Comment: muito obrigado amigo, salvou minha vida

Comment: @Sam, eu coloquei "separado" levando em consideração o código original, onde ele colocou um keyup dentro de outro keyup.